# Regular Expression - DLE not handled

Tags: c#-2.0

I need to discard ASCII Control Characters in SOAP response, since these control characters dont allow to form a valid XML data.

I have used the below Regular Expression to discard the control characters,

@"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]"

But the ASCII Control Character - DLE (Data Link Escape) is not handled in the above REGEX.

Please help me on the Regular Expression, that will discard all the ASCII Control Characters.

Comment: Why is the web service sending you control characters in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

DLE is `\x10`, that is not in your regex.

Also, you seem to be discard all alpha numeric characters too with `\x20-\xD7FF`. Is that correct?

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 0):

The went through the link given.

http://www.theplancollection.com/house-plan-related-articles/hexadecimal-value-invalid-character

As per the link, the below mentioned regex is for the set of valid XML characters.

```
string re = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
return Regex.Replace(text, re, "");
```

I believe the DLE comes in this set of valid expression itself. hence it not getting replaced. I am not familiar with regular expression. Please correct me if I am wrong.